# What limits are there on taking missions?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I seem to recall reading somewhere that you were limited to only two missions at a time, but since many of the missions seem to not be completable when you receive them, this doesn't seem to make much sense.  What are the limits in terms of taking missions?  What happens if you reach that limit and then talk to someone that would normally give you a mission?  Is there a way to review the missions that you are currently on?

Comment: I'm not positive, but I've never found two missions at the same place. At least usually, if not always, you only get one or two missions at the start and more unlock when you complete that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take 2 missions at a time per area per timezone.

I'm not sure about what happens if you accept more than 2 missions i cant help you on that.

There is no overview of all the missions you are currently doing. But you can see all the missions you are doing in the area you are in now by opening the map for the current area.

Comment: you can't accept more than 2 missions, the npcs that would give you missions otherwise simply aren't talkable when you have 2 missions open ;) (believe me, i tried >.<)